# URL redirect using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I have changed my normal™ php website to CodeIgniter framework. My issue is

**I need to:**

> redirect http://samajam.org/contact_us.php to 
>   http://samajam.org/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Redirect 301 /contact_us.php http://samajam.org/contact
```

Enjoy, i hope i helped you :)

Comment: thanks its working but now the url is like `http://samajam.org/contact?/contact_us.php` i just need `samajam.org/contact` is it possible

Comment: try adding the whole qualified name of the domain in the first parameter (  `http://samajam.org/contact_us.php` ), but I dont have an Apache at hand to try it now. (I'm at work and here we use different technology, sorry!)

Answer (score 2):

You can set 301 redirection in your .htaccess file like -

```
Redirect 301 http://samajam.org/contact_us.php http://samajam.org/contact
```

OR you can use [CodeIgniter URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/url_helper.html) for redirection